# Google Calendar Sync Error on Bookly Plugin Wordpress Token Expired or Revoked

Tags: wordpress, google-calendar-api

I am new to this clients website and he has the bookly plugin for his staff member. The staff member goes on vacation for a couple of weeks and when he comes back google calendar doesnt sync his appointments. When I click his username It shows me this error.

**Google Calendar: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked." }'**

Im just stuck on how to fix this.

I tried to have him log into and update his chrome, I also synced the whole staff calendar from the  wordpress dashboard. The last thing i tried was to send him instructions on how to check he is not blocking it on his google chrome. Waiting for him to respond to that but wanted to get some help if anyone ran into this error message before.